# Microsoft Bot Framework Reset Bot by Typing "Reset" not Working in Azure

Tags: c#, botframework

i have a simple bot such that when the user types the word "reset" and send to the bot, the bot resets itself.
I have a code here but it works in Localhost Emulator, but when I publish to Azure, it does not work?

Where am I wrong??

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        //if the user types certain messages, quit all dialogs and start over
        string msg = activity.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        if (msg == "start over" || msg == "exit" || msg == "quit" || msg == "done" || msg == "start again" || msg == "restart" || msg == "leave" || msg == "reset")
        {
            //    //This is where the conversation gets reset!
            await activity.GetStateClient().BotState
                        .DeleteStateForUserWithHttpMessagesAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);

        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        var clearMsg = activity.CreateReply();

        clearMsg.Text = $"Lets star";
        await client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(clearMsg);
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new BookRoom());


        }
        else
        {
            //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            //Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
            //reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            //reply.Text = null;
            //await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            //and even if we reset everything, show the welcome message again
            //  BotUtils.SendTyping(activity); //send "typing" indicator upon each message received
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new BookRoom());
        }


        //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Any help, I will appreciate..

Comment: `when I publish to Azure, it does not work?` Which channel do you test with your bot? does not working mean exceptions or no response?

Comment: You can try to add the host of service url to trusted hosts: `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);var client = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl),new MicrosoftAppCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]));`

Comment: Where should I add it on?? on Controller or on the Global asax file

Comment: Web chat, skype and Messenger are the channels am using

Comment: To reiterate, can you confirm if the non-reset messages actually get a response from the bot or do all messages fail? Is it just the "reset" messages that fail? If so, this could also be due to using the default state service, you can look into switching to tablestorage instead [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) and [here](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/02/reminder-the-bot-framework-state-service-has-been-retired-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: To note, you can add the TrustServiceUrl anywhere before calls to activity.